# Difference between panend and pancancel in Hammer.js?

Tags: javascript, frontend, hammer.js, pan

I can't find the difference anywhere in the documentation between `panend` and `pancancel` handlers for `pan` events in Hammer.js documentation - what is the difference between the two?

I imagine swiping off screen on mobile devices but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

pancancel will trigger when pointercancel native event is triggered. For example, when browser detects that you are trying to scroll rather than pointermove, the pointercancel will be dispatched.

and it's annoying that unwilling pointercancel happens on Android when the element has `touch-action: pan-y`.